# Eclipselink translatedsqlstring exception

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a simple JPA entity with **@AdditionalCriteria** mentioned for the login language. I also have specified a query redirector for this class. When I attempt to get the translated sql string in the query redirector, I get a null pointer exception. The reason is that the field in the entity is called lang and the additional criteria parameter is LOGIN_LANGUAGE. The exception is thrown when the line 273 of class **org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ParameterExpression** is executed.

My JPA entity looks like this

```
@QueryRedirectors(allQueries=VPMQueryRedirector.class)
@AdditionalCriteria(value = "this.lang = :LOGIN_LANGUAGE")
public class AuthorityTextView extends EntityCommons implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AUTHORITYID", length = 36)
    private String authorityId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LANG", length = 2)
    private String lang;

    @Column(name = "AUTHORITYTEXT", length = 255)
    private String authorityText;

    @Column(name = "DEFAULTUSED")
    private Boolean defaultUsed; 


    public String getAuthorityId() {
        return authorityId;
    }

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public String getAuthorityText() {
        return this.authorityText;
    }

    public Boolean getDefaultUsed() {
        return this.defaultUsed;
    }
}
```

My Query Redirector is listed below

```
public class VPMQueryRedirector implements QueryRedirector {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3912645701055442481L;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public Object invokeQuery(DatabaseQuery query, Record arguments, Session session) {

        query.setDoNotRedirect(true);
        String translatedSQLString = query.getTranslatedSQLString(session, arguments);
        }
```

I have create a bug under [eclipselink](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=563156), but there hasn't been any updates yet if the observation is correct or not.

Comment: Your view of the code won't be the same as anyone else's, as it is version specific, so a line number doesn't help yourself. Bugs etc need versions and stack traces to be relevant. You are telling EclipseLink that the query needs a LOGIN_LANGUAGE session parameter- how are you passing that in?

Comment: Hi Chris,
The line number is in the standard eclipselink class **ParameterExpression** and should be same for everyone. Also the LOGIN_LANGUAGE is added to the entity manager using

`entityManager.setProperty(ProjectConstants.LOGIN_LANGUAGE, loginLanguage);`

Comment: Line numbers change between releases - I don't even bother looking anymore unless there is a stack trace showing me the method name so I can tell how drastically the code I'm looking at differs from the code someone is using and getting the problem. Never assume something is standard and constant - nothing ever is. Are you able to debug this code? What is null specifically? Line 273 in the code I see is value = session.getProperty(this.field.getName());, so is it the session or the field that is null?